# Doctrine losing persistence state of entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My entities are **driver** and **position**. A driver can have many positions (gps data). I also have a method in my drivers repo which gives me all the drivers with their latest position.

```
public function getDriversWithCurrentPosition()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d, p.lat, p.lng')
        ->leftJoin('d.positions', 'p')
        ->where('p.timeCreated = (SELECT MAX(p2.timeCreated) FROM AppBundle\Entity\Position p2 WHERE p2.driver = d) OR p.timeCreated IS NULL')
        ->groupBy('p.driver')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Now I wrote a symfony command to generate random positions for all existing drivers. The command generates let's say 1000 position entities and flushes after every 100 iterations and also changes the related driver randomly.

```
/**
 * The returned drivers array looks like this:
 * [
 *    [0 => driver-entity, 'lat' => 52.5634, 'lng' => 8.4535],
 *    [0 => driver-entity, 'lat' => 52.7434, 'lng' => 8.3434],
 *    ...
 * ]
 */
$drivers = $driverRepo->getDriversWithCurrentPosition();
$driver = $drivers ? $drivers[0] : null;
$number = 1000;
while ($number) {
    // generate new lat/lng based on drivers current position
    $lat = $driver['lat'] + ...;
    $lng = $driver['lng'] + ...;

    // creating new entity
    $position = new Position();
    $position->setDriver($driver[0]);
    $position->setLat($lat);
    $position->setLng($lng);

    $this->em->persist($position);

    if (!($number % 100)) {
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear();
        // change driver
        $driver = $drivers[rand(0, count($drivers) - 1)];
    }

    $number--;
}

$this->em->flush();
$this->em->clear();
```

So every 100 position entities generated by this command, the related driver entity should change. But as soon as it gets to the 101st iteration the driver entity is not recognized as managed by doctrine and the following exception is thrown:

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
>   A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Position#driver' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   AppBundle\Entity\Driver@000000003412a11000007f77533bcf9d. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Driver#__toString()' to get a clue.

**UPDATE**

It is the `flush` and `clear` inside the loop which causes the problem.

The first 100 position entities with the driver entity from above the loop are saved correctly.

When I change

```
$position->setDriver($driver[0]);
```

to

```
$position->setDriver($driverRepo->find($driver[0]->getId()));
```

it works.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**UPDATE 2**

A quick fix is refreshing the drivers array in the lopp:

```
if (!($number % 100)) {
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->clear();
    // change driver
    $drivers = $driverRepo->getDriversWithCurrentPosition();
    $driver = $drivers[rand(0, count($drivers) - 1)];
}
```

Comment: Have you any `position` property inside `Drive` class? If yes, do you really need it? Is only the class `Driver` displayed if you do `var_dump($driver[0])` after `if (!($number % 100)) {`?

Comment: I just recognized that it has nothing to do with the change of the driver entity. It is the flush and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not clear when flushing.

```
if (!($number % 100)) {
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear(); <-HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        // change driver
        $driver = $drivers[rand(0, count($drivers) - 1)];
    }
```

Call clear only at the end of the command.
If you are worried about the memory consumption then clear only certain entities (the $position in your case, but you'll have to keep them in an array and then iterate over it and clear them with $this-em->clear($position) )